# Which framework should I use with cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm making a Single Page Application using cytoscape.js. Which framework should I use with cytoscape.js?

I read the [factsheet of cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#introduction/factsheet). The link says cytoscape.js is a dependency free library, but if I remove jQuery from my demo, cytoscape.js can't render the content. I think Cytoscape.js depends jQuery.

Why does the factsheet say **Dependency free**? If I have to use jQuery, the javascript client framework is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape doesn't require jQuery. In [Cytoscape's initialisation documentation](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/index.html#core/initialisation), under the "getting started" header, it shows an example of how to initialise the library without jQuery:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  ready: function(){ console.log('ready') }
});
```

It's hard to guess what exactly is happening to your code since you haven't posted it in the question, but if you add it I'll try to update this answer to address it specifically.